# Can we get a python environment built in debug mode using conda?

Tags: python, debugging, build, conda

Conda environments are Python distributions built in release mode, but for my Python extension module it would be helpful to be able to use conda to link Python in Debug mode. So can we build a conda environment in debug mode?

Something like:

```
conda create --name py39_d python=3.9 --config Debug
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for Conda Forge, **the answer is currently *no***.

Adding debug builds [has been in discussion](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/issues/73) for several years. According to [a 2020 issue](https://github.com/conda-forge/conda-forge.github.io/issues/1017), there was previously a lack of infrastructure to support it, but that had mostly been worked out. Given how few people commented on the post, it seems there simply hasn't been enough interest expressed. If you'd like such builds to be available, then I'd suggest joining the conversation.